# Set Up Admin Users to Edit Users, Articles, Collaborators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to solve an issue I'm having with setting up admin on my site. Here is a simple version of my routes.

```
resources :users
  resources :articles
  resources :collaborators
end

resources :admin
```

Admin users are very similar to Collaborators, because they can edit and create Articles, but Admin has the ability to also c.r.u.d. Users, Collaborators, and Articles for every User. Collaborators can only c.r.u.d. Articles that are associated with the User they have been assigned to.

The part where this gets a little bit confusing is how to set up the controller and views that Admin uses for CRUD operations. As of now the way I am trying to implement it is to create separate CRUD views within admin/. The problem with this is that the functionality is so simimlar to a collaborator, I feel like it could be DRYer somehow.

Anybody know the most basic way to implement something like this? Thanks!

Update: I'd like to update this to say that it's super easy to google admin tools for rails. I'm more wondering how to implement this without an admin tool, or if that sounds like a bad idea, why?

Comment: Have you considered in using authorization gems like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/) or something relatively new like [The Role](https://github.com/the-teacher/the_role)?

By using those you could just have one view for all role types and have the gems help you with authorization.

Comment: i'm not so much concerned about authorization as i am about the structure of views for editing content. i will definitely look at CanCan and The Role for the auth but hoping to find a good structure for the admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I came up with is to create Collaborators with an admin field true / false. I also set up CanCan and it's working pretty nicely.

Here is my CanCan ability.rb

def initialize(user)

```
if user.admin?
  can :manage, :all
else 
  can :manage, Article, :id => user.article_id
  cannot :index, Article
end
```

end

I just used "user" because it's more readable and shorter than collaborator and basically a user...

Answer (score 0):

Try ActiveAdmin [(http://activeadmin.info/](http://activeadmin.info/)). I think it is the most simplest way to build administrator backend for your application.

Comment: although you may be totally right that i should use a system like this, part of the reason why i'm not excited about it is because some of these systems have so many bells and whistles... then when it comes time to customize it's a pain. i will definitely take a look and see if it could fit my basic needs. ideally i'd like to have *nearly* the same interface for creating Users, Articles, and Collaborators as a normal user or Collaborator would have.